# Relevant Job Ad

Tags: discussion, advertising, jobs

I believe it will be faster to search a potential employee by targeting the job add to him.

If someone looking for a job passively and he opens a particular question to see the answer in stackoverflow, then chances are more that ad being viewed if it is related to him.

i.e. If I am looking at question related to WCF (i.e. TAG with WCF,.NET ...) then there are more chances that I click on the job if it is related to the TAG of questions WCF not RUBY! (this is just an example)

I think so it is fairly straightforward to achieve this and will be more fruitful when there will be more jobs on the stackoverflow job-board.

Same thing can be looked for other ads around stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a request for Fog Creek.

At the very least, Fog Creek should be geolocating the IP.

We *could* pass them the tags from the page (if any) as that might be less narrow than Random City, Random Country.

However, I suspect there aren't quite enough job listings (I mean, you'd need thousands and thousands) to make this kind of targetting worthwhile.

Comment: They could _try_ to find a relevant ad, and then server a random ad if there were no good matches from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass them the set of interesting tags I have, that would help I think.